# R: assign() in loop in both side

Tags: r

Can the following script be automated using loop syntax?

```
diet1.df <- opfile_diet1[, 100:200]
diet2.df <- opfile_diet2[, 100:200]
diet3.df <- opfile_diet3[, 100:200]
```

Here, loop syntax should be assign both side.
So I tried like as follow but it wasn't working.

```
diet.list <- c("diet1", "diet2", "diet3)
for (diet in diet.list){

assign(sprintf("%s.df", diet), sprintf("opfile_%s[, 100:200]", diet))

}
```

It was not dataframe. It is string like as follow.
diet1.df <- "opfile_diet1[, 100:200]"

Could you give some idea?
Thank you :)

Comment: Using `assign` in this way isn't a good idea (in fact, normal code simply never needs to use `assign`; the purpose of this function is for low-level metaprogramming), and having consecutively numbered variable names pretty much *always* means that you should be using a list instead: `diet.df` and `opfile_diet`.

Comment: Keep the subsets of dataframes in a list, something like: `myList <- lapply(ls(pattern = "^opfile_diet"), function(i) i[, 100:200] )`

Comment: Why not just keep it simple and have everything in a list instead of polluting the environment. Please follow the advice given above

Answer (score 0):

While @Konrad's comment is correct, if you really want to use `assign` you need to `get` to get the actual value of the object from a character vector containing its name.

```
assign(sprintf("%s.df", diet), get(sprintf("opfile_%s[, 100:200]", diet)))
```

But, really, consider using a list. it will make your life easier. Follow zx8754 comment.

Comment: Actually, my question was simplified one. I have lots of list and lines. So I need it to automatizing. And I solved this problem with you comments with little modifying. Thank you! ` assign(sprintf("%s.df", dit), get(sprintf("opfile_%s", diet.num))[,100:200]) `